# How do I bind a field to a control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

Assume there is a class Person {Name} and we want to bind the name of the person to a textbox.text property.
How is this accomplished?

something similar to:

```
nameTextbox.DataBindings.Add(...)
```

I have done this in WPF using DepedencyProperties but haven't find anything similar to WinForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is amazingly simple. Seems to be working out of the box. I must bee blind for not figuring this earlier

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.Name = "Odys";
textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", person1, "Name");
```

Works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and use the Person instance as DataSource for this. Then you have to bind the TextBox Text Property to the BindingSource.